# Firefox HTML inspector, add a new css rule with custom selector

Tags: css, firefox, inspector

I can do the same in chrome but I'm unable to see how can I do the same add rule thing in firefox?

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who comes across this in the future:

Firefox currently (as of version 31) doesn't let you do this in the same way Chrome does (from the CSS rules in the inspector tab), but it does let you add your own rules.

1. Go to the **Style Editor** tab (Shift + 7)
2. Click the **New** button on the left to create a new stylesheet
3. Type your CSS rules in the new style sheet.

The new rules should get updated on the page as soon as you finish typing them.

Comment: It's Shift + **F7** on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the styles section and right-click. You will have an option called 'Add Rule'.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that this IMHO only works with the firebug plugin installed.
In the plain FF debugging utils I can also not find any way to directly add new CSS rules.